# rebase: Reset First Commit in Interactive Rebase

Tags: git

Usually when editing a commit in interactive rebase I do the following when it stops on an `edit` line:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

to reset the commits' files. However, when the rebase was started from `--root` with

```
git rebase -i --root
```

and we are editing the very first commit, this can obviously not be done because `HEAD^` doesn't exist.

How do I perform the reset for the very first commit within an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 1):

In that case : it is easier to use `commit --amend` after staging the edited content.

---

I don't see a straightforward way to emulate a "git reset on emptyness" with a detached HEAD :
`git` accpets to have `ref: refs/non_existing_ref` int its `HEAD` file, but refuses to have an empty `HEAD` file.

A hacky way would  be :

```
# pseudo code, the following is not valid syntax in any language

if current HEAD has no parent :
    # create a phony ref :
    echo "ref: refs/hacky_reset_root_commit" > .git/HEAD
    # the index already holds the content of current commit
else :
    git reset --soft HEAD^

# proceed with your processing ...

git commit

if '.git/HEAD' content is 'ref: refs/hacky_reset_root_commit' :
    # switch back to detached HEAD mode :
    git checkout $(git rev-parse HEAD)
    # delete phony ref :
    git update-ref -d refs/hacky_reset_root_commit
else:
    # nothing more to do
```

Comment: I know, but in this case this is an automated task, so I'd need a consistent way to do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity : can you describe your use case ? what part is automated in your usage of `git rebase -i` ?

Comment: It can be done on a script setting `GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true`. `GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true git commit --amend`

Comment: I'm editting my answer : in this context, `git commit-tree` is just a more complicated way to run `git commit --amend`, I'm removing this suggestion and leaving the `commit --amend` variant